# AngularJS Nested ng-repeat Not Working in Version 1.2.1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a system where I would like to nest two ng-repeat statements so that I can work my way through a 2D array.  I was able to complete the task successfully using version 1.1.1 as you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/skArT/1/

However, when I take the exact same code set and change the version of Angular to 1.2.1 the code no longer works and throws an error:

http://jsfiddle.net/skArT/2/

**Error:**

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: x in value, Duplicate key: number:0
```

So my question is, how can I accomplish the task shown in version 1.1.1 with newer versions of Angular?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need to do is read the error message and listen to it. Change:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in value">{{x}}</div>
```

To:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in value track by $index">{{x}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `track by` clause solves this. It seems rather trivial to me for it to be required in your case.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <span ng-repeat="(index, value) in field">        
        <div ng-repeat="(key,x) in value track by key">{{x}}</div>
        <br/>
    </span>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/92bSt/

Comment: Yeah, it seems obvious now after seeing the solution that the error was pointing me in the right direction.  I have just never seen 'track by' in any logical operation in another language.  Nothing experientially was pointing me toward that solution.